# remove # from url gives 404 error angular5

Tags: server

The thing is I was trying to remove the # from the angular 5 application.
I was successful in doing so, the app is also working fine but the problem is the internal links are giving 404 error when I try to reload or refresh the page

for eg,

> www.example.com (is working fine on reload and refresh).

*----------but----------*

> www.example.com/jobs (gives 404 error on reload and refresh)

/jobs : is part of routing

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Do you have a `.htaccess` file inside your project root folder?

Comment: This is a server issue : your server tries to serve the page requested by the URL the user provides. This isn't an Angular issue, this is a server issue. You need to redirect every request to display your `index.html` file. I'm removing the Angular tag, and I let you put the tag for the server you use instead.

Comment: thanks for the help guys but fortunately i was able to sole the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Create a `.htaccess` file inside your root folder (next the `package.json` file) and paste this code to its content:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: And what if he uses NodeJS ?

Comment: thanks for the help guys but fortunately i was able to sole the problem.